# Can't sync/authenticated wp/wc plugins

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

The plugin is trying to access to:
https://my.site/wc-auth/v1/authorize,
and the results is 404,
The thing is the if I try to access to:
https://my.site/index.php/wc-auth/v1/authorize
It's working and I can't figure it out why it's happening,

Permalinks set to 'Post',
REST API (both legacy and latest vertion) is enabled,
WP 4.8.9
WC 3.5.1

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
I changed all of the AllowOverride variables in httpd.conf to All,
Now everything is working.